# vb. net bindingsource filter

Tags: vb.net, binding, filtering

i using visual.net  2012 - i am using this  code to filter bindingsource by textbox - all work ok but when i delete the text in textbox the bindingsource show only rows that have value in it .. 
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = "[REF] LIKE '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'"
End Sub
```

how can i make it to show all when i delete the text from textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the filter if there is no text:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = If((TextBox2.Text.Length > 0), "[REF] LIKE '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'", "")
End Sub
```